# calling a jquery function and passing it an object on arrow keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, keypress

Trying to call a function "clickEvent()" and pass it an obj with attributes on arrow-keyUp using jQuery. But Im not reaching the function. Here is the code. Thanks.

**Please Note: Im forking existing code, but adding my arrowPress events to it. So everything should remain as is expect for the document ready if (direction != null) area.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        var direction = null;

        // handle cursor keys
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            // slide left
            direction = 'prev';
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            // slide right
            direction = 'next';
        }

        if (direction != null) {
            //alert($('.'+ direction).attr('rel'));
            //need to pass the alert above as an obj to the function clickEvent() below.
        }
    });

}); //end $(document).ready


//function on external .js src
(function($) {
    function clickEvent(obj) {
        alert(obj.attr("rel"));
    }

    $.fn.slidingPage = function(options) {
        $el = $(this);
    }
})(jQuery); //end ext js scr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to wrap your code into anonymous function to prevent global variable pollution, then your event and function code should be put in the same scope.

You probably need to trigger click event on .prev and .next.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        var direction = null;

        // handle cursor keys
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            // slide left
            direction = 'prev';
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            // slide right
            direction = 'next';
        }

        if (direction != null) {
            $('.'+ direction).click()
        }
    });

}); //end $(document).ready
```

Comment: breaks the existing forked code and still doesnt work on arrowPress. All I think I should change is the info in the If != null statement or as less changes to the ext js as possible.

Comment: Which code is yours and which is forked code? If `external .js src` is forked, then please provide some additional info on how clickEvent is used in the forked code. If its bound to some elements, then you may just trigger it on them without modifying the js file.

Comment: this is what i got, from the prev btn

<a class="prev" style="top: 180px; " rel="external" href="#" title="external page" data-transition="{"easing": "easeInOutQuint", "slideScroll": "vertical", "callback":""}">Prev</a>

Comment: If the button already works, then why won't you just trigger its clicked event on document keypressed event? Have you tried putting `$('.'+ direction).click()` inside the `if (direction != null)` check?

Comment: ha!!!!!! grrrrr!!! it works... I thought it was something simple. I was reading all kinds of stuff, and trying so many other things, just not that. Thanks bud. I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

The function `clickEvent` is inside another function's scope, put them into the same scope, or higher scope:

```
function clickEvent(obj) {
    alert(obj.attr("rel"));
}

$.fn.slidingPage = function(options) {
    var $el = $(this);
};

(function($) {
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        var direction = null;

        // handle cursor keys
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            // slide left
            direction = 'prev';
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            // slide right
            direction = 'next';
        }

        if (direction != null) {
            clickEvent( $('.'+ direction) );
        }
    });

});
```

There is no reason for the `clickEvent` and `slidingPage` declarations to be inside a document ready handler.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that Im forking existing code, but adding my arrowPress events to it. So everything should remain as is expect for the document ready if (direction != null) area.

Comment: @fhonics only the external.js needs to be changed. If you cannot change it, you cannot call the function in there because it's inside a function

Comment: ok thought it would be simple. I can try though. JS is not my background so I dont want to be missing about too much with lots of existing code that already works. but i will try and let u know in a few thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrey Kuzmin...

```
if (direction != null) {

   $('.'+ direction).click();       

}
```